# использование await без async

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, async-await

Возникли некоторые проблемы при разборе данной темы. Вопрос конкретно про возможность использования await вне функции async.
Вот код:

```
let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
let data = await response.json();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прочитайте [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) первое предложение

Comment: Если мы попробуем использовать await внутри функции, объявленной без async, получим синтаксическую ошибку

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как правило `await` можно использовать **только** внутри функции `async`

Однако, некоторые браузеры предоставляют возможность `top-level await`, когда разрешено использовать `await` на самом верхнем глобальном уровне.

Именно это и продемонстрировано на картинке: запуск в глобальном скопе в консоли.